# How to have a VB.NET Active Directory login form raise authenticated event back to main form

Tags: vb.net, forms, events, authentication, active-directory

I have a small VB.NET application which at present has two forms; 
The first is the main form in which users have a choice of buttons to click. I have a second form which handles authentication against Active Directory. When the user clicks 'OK' on the login form a public property called 'Authenticated' is set to 'True'.
What I want but am really struggling to get my head around is;
On the main form, when a user clicks one of the buttons, it to check the value of the 'Authenticated' property and if it is false to launch the Login form. This bit works fine but what I am unsure how to do is have the main form wait until the user has entered their credentials and clicked okay, and then to be able to re-check the 'Authenticated' status before perform an action on the button.

This subject has loosely been covered before in this post - [Showing Login form before main form in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291708/showing-login-form-before-main-form-in-vb-net/1294352#1294352?newreg=2bbdca1ab9d14117a5836a383ffb871b)

And the last comment is from someone from Beth who mentions being able to do by the sounds of it exactly what I'm trying to achieve by raising an event from the login form... I wonder if anyone is able to give me more details on how I may be able to accomplish this at all?

Many thanks for your time.

James

Comment: This is very unwise and not infrequently a serious security leak.  Users already authenticate themselves, they use the battle-scarred and very secure Windows login screen.  "Authenticated" is already true, they can't start your program without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fairly straight forward.

In your startup form add an `Authenticated` property and default this to `False`

On form load show the Authentication form:

```
Public Class frmMain

    Friend Property Authenticated As Boolean = False

    Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If Not _authenticated Then frmAuthenticate.ShowDialog()
        If _authenticated Then
            MessageBox.Show("You have been authenticated")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("You have not authenticated")
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then in your authenication form, only set the main forms Authenticated property to true if the authentication worked:

```
Public Class frmAuthenticate

    Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
        If AuthenticatedOK() Then frmMain.Authenticated = True
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Function AuthenticatedOK() As Boolean
        Return False 'do your auth logic here
    End Function

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks very much for your prompt reply. I'd already done the majority of what you were suggesting, the only real difference was I had created the public 'Authenticated' property on the login page and was setting them directly their, rather than from the main form as you suggested... I have tried switching them round to the main form but that didn't seem to help. My problem is that I can't call the login on form load due to the way I need my app to work. It has to be called on press of any number of buttons on the main form... I hope this makes sense! :/ Many thanks.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether this is done in Form_load or on a button click, it should still work the same. Are you using `ShowDialog` when you show the authentication form?

Comment: Ah. No. I was just using 'Show'! Woops, massive school boy error! Thank you very much for pointing out my idiocy! ;)